# Why are datatype settings different between .dtproj and .dtsx files?

Tags: ssis

There seems to be a significant difference between the datatype values stored in the .dtproj and .dtsx files. I created a project deployment package in VS 2017 and added a package parameter for each type available. Is this as-designed? Am I missing something?

[image: Variable datatype differences]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DTSX is the Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services package file format.

DTPROJ is the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools project file format.

The "DataType values" you see correspond to enumerations specific (and apparently unique) to the individual file formats. It's not really designed to be such, it just ended up that way. These two formats were defined possibly by different teams, at different times, and toward different goals. While it would be nice if both file formats used the same enumeration they just they don't... and that's okay, because the responsible code will decode these values into typed variables compatible with one another... it's okay so long as only code modifies them.

It is nice that these formats are human readable being that they are in a variant of XML, it's unfortunate that the data within is practically incomprehensible. Using integers to represent types and decoding with arbitrary enumerations doesn't really lend these formats to be human modifiable without considerable risk of introducing bugs making the human readability of the format pointless.

Comment: I do appreciate that these files are in plain-text that can be read by humans, but more easily and often correctly by code. It is far better than a proprietary binary format for which Microsoft and other closed-source vendors are known.

Comment: It's a step in the right direction to be sure, but there's a big difference to being open, and being understandable.